# Inline __asm code for getting the address of TIB (fs:[0x18])

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I'd like to get the TIB of a process and afterwards get its PEB and so forth. I'm failing to do so because I'm having some issues with the `__readfsdword(0x18)` function, so I'd like to do it with `__asm` inline code, if possible.
The program is compiled for x86, so I think it means that the TIB will be located at offset `0x18` from the FS register. On x64 it should be on `gs:[0x30]`.

How would I implement this inline assembly idea?

## Edit

`NtCurrentTeb()` and `__readfsdword` gave different return addresses so I wanted to get as low-level as possible to figure out which one was malfunctioning.
The reason why `__readfsdword` wasn't working is because I think the libraries weren't compatible with each other, so I replaced them with the updated versions and now it's working properly.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). There is no need to use Inline Assembly for this. Can you tell us how using `__readfsdword(0x18)` failed? Maybe provide some code. fs:0x18 is the Thread Environment Block (aka TIB) in 32-bit Windows code. It sounds like the code that used `__readfsdword` is incorrect.

Comment: *having some issues with the __readfsdword(0x18)* and in what issue ? in what problem use [`NtCurrentTeb()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-ntcurrentteb) ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch @RbMM Sorry for the late replies... I've had some trouble with importing libraries and NtCurrentTeb() was differing from `__readfsdword(0x18)` although NtCurrentTeb() is basically a `return (void*)__readfsdword(0x18);`, so I wanted to get as low-level as possible. I've replaced the headers that I used with the updated ones.

Comment: @Xyzzel - any libraries here absolute unrelated. `__readfsdword` is compiler intrinsic. and `NtCurrentTeb()` - inline function which call `__readfsdword(0x18)` for *x86* case - so result can not be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__readfsdword`/`__readgsqword` are compiler intrinsic functions that will generate more optimized code, there is no reason to use inline assembly. Inline assembly is not even supported by Microsoft's compilers for 64-bit targets.

```
#include <intrin.h>

__declspec(naked) void* __stdcall GetTEB()
{
    __asm mov eax, dword ptr fs:[0x18] ;
    __asm ret ;
}

...

void *teb;
__asm push eax ;
__asm mov eax, dword ptr fs:[0x18] ;
__asm mov teb, eax ;
__asm pop eax ;
printf("%p == %p == %p\n", GetTEB(), teb, __readfsdword(0x18));
```

And as suggested in the comments, [NtCurrentTeb()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-ntcurrentteb) is provided by the Windows SDK. It most likely just uses `__readfsdword`.

Comment: Thanks! I've explained in the comments, I had some issues with the libraries.